# GCP mongodb external ip connection issue

Tags: spring, mongodb, google-cloud-platform

I have a `spring MVC application` and I am connecting it to `MongoDB` cluster

This is in the `application.properties` file

```
mongodb.url=mongodb://userName:Password@xx.xx.x.xx:27017,xx.xx.x.xx:27017,xx.xx.x.xx:27017/?authSource=admin
```

The cluster is deployed on `GCP` with one primary and 2 secondary servers.
However, after deployment when I hit the `API` to get the data I get an  error

`{java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb-3-arbiters-vm-0}}, {address=mongodb-3-servers-vm-1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb-3-servers-vm-1}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb-3-servers-vm-1}}`

The external `IPs` are getting mapped to the server name on the `GCP` dashboard. `xx.xx.xx.xx:27017 to mongodb-3-servers-vm-1:27017`, hence resulting in unknown host exception. what to do to avoid that ?

Comment: Is this a replica set? Your connection string doesn't include a replica set name, but there are multiple hosts.

Comment: one is the primary and the other 2 are replica sets(secondary)... there is no sharding done ..

Answer (score 1):

When connecting to a replica set, the hostnames, IP addresses and port numbers provided in the connection string are the seedlist.

The driver will connect to the hosts in the seedlist in order to get an initial connection.  It uses this connection to perform server discovery.  It queries the server that is connected first for the host names, port numbers, and status of the other members of the replica set.  The server obtains this information from the replica set configuration document.

This means that the hostnames and port number you used when running `rs.initiate` or `rs.add` must be resolvable by both the replica set members and each client host that will be connecting.

There is a feature that supports passing remote clients a different host name, similar to split-horizon DNS, but outside of the git repository, I don't see any mention of it.