# MongoDB: connect to a replicaSet running on docker (local)

Tags: mongodb, docker, replicaset

I've doing a POC on mongo replica sets in a local containerized environment. I have been able to create a simple mongodb replica set and initialize it.  The three nodes are running on the default port (27017) internally and are mapped/exposed using ports 35000, 35001, and 35002.  The container names are mongo0, mongo1, and mongo2 respectively.  The replica set is named 'rst'.  I have added entries in my hosts file to map names mongo(0..2) to 127.0.0.1.

When I initate the replica set, I get an OK response and I am able to connect to each node with Compass using direct connect option (directConnection=true) 3500N port.  e.g.: `mongodb://mongo0:35000/&directConnection=true` However, when I attempt to connect using `mongodb://mongo0:35000/&replicaSet=rst?`, I am receiving the following error:

`connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`

I also tried: `mongodb://mongo0:35000,mongo1:35001,mongo2:35002?replicaSet=rst` with the same result.

I should note that from within one of the nodes, this connection string works to connect to mongosh: `mongosh mongodb://mongo0,mongo1,mongo2?replicaSet=rst`.
 
I know why it's trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 (hosts mapping) but I don't understand why it's trying to connect on port 27017 given that I specified a different port in the connection string.  Is there some other connection option?  An explanation for this behavior would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147478/2282634

Comment: @Joe I think it explains the behavior I am seeing.  I take it that there's no (documented) alternative to work around that?  I'm not sure if this will be an issue when implementing in a test or production k8s environment.

Answer (score 0):

I see that @Joe has already answered this at least a couple of times.  For anyone who comes across while troubleshooting a similar issue, here are those links:

- [MongoDB replica set hostnames - client vs. server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524602/mongodb-replica-set-hostnames-client-vs-server)
- [GCP mongodb external ip connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120345/gcp-mongodb-external-ip-connection-issue)

I also found this which offers some solutions:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/859503/how-can-i-connect-to-a-mongodb-replica-set-behind-a-proxy

For resolving the port number discrepancy, the simple solution is to use the non-standard port in the mongo container.  That is, start it on whatever port will be mapped to it when exposing the port.

For managing the host names, I like the solution in the last question above of using `etc/hosts` inside the container to create an alias(es) that matches the DNS name(s) that the client will see.  Then that hostname can be used for bind_ip and to initialize the replicaSet.